# How to return the most recent children unique by parent with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

A post `has_many` comments. A comment `belongs_to` a post. I'm trying to get back a list of the most recent comments, but only one per post.

The following SQL returns the correct comments results set in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT
  comments.*
FROM
  (SELECT
     post_id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
   FROM
     comments
   GROUP BY
     post_id) AS latest_comments
INNER JOIN
  comments
ON
  comments.post_id = latest_comments.post_id AND
  comments.created_at = latest_comments.created_at
```

How can I define a query to return the same result set with ActiveRecord?

Comment: Nice question. I presume you want a single SQL query constructed by Active Record, rather than loading the posts and mapping the comments? Such as `Post.includes(:comments).map { |post| post.comments.a_recent_scope.first }`.

Comment: Did you look over [find_by_sql](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql) ?

Comment: @SRack correct, looking for a single query ActiveRecord solution for efficiency and to keep the result set as a relation rather than an array.

Comment: @razvans thanks. Will use `find_by_sql` if there's no better way to describe this query with the ActiveRecord DSL.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly the equivalent of your SQL, but I believe should also work:

```
Comment.where(
  created_at: Comment.select('max(created_at)').group(:post_id)
)
# Comment Load (6.9ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."created_at" IN (
#   SELECT max(created_at) FROM "comments" GROUP BY "comments"."post_id"
# ) LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```